# How to map two columns using the same dictionary

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe describing a network by linking two nodes together with a weight:

```py
import polars as pl
df_network = pl.DataFrame(
    {"node1": ["a", "c", "c"], "node2": ["b", "d", "a"], "weight": [1, 2, 3]}
)
# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌───────┬───────┬────────┐
# │ node1 ┆ node2 ┆ weight │
# │ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
# │ str   ┆ str   ┆ i64    │
# ╞═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
# │ a     ┆ b     ┆ 1      │
# │ c     ┆ d     ┆ 2      │
# │ c     ┆ a     ┆ 3      │
# └───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

And a dictionary that maps a node to an integer index:

```py
df_node_index = pl.DataFrame({"node": ["d", "b", "c", "a"], "index": [0, 1, 2, 3]})
# shape: (4, 2)
# ┌──────┬───────┐
# │ node ┆ index │
# │ ---  ┆ ---   │
# │ str  ┆ i64   │
# ╞══════╪═══════╡
# │ d    ┆ 0     │
# │ b    ┆ 1     │
# │ c    ┆ 2     │
# │ a    ┆ 3     │
# └──────┴───────┘
```

What is an elegant polars way to map the nodes to their index, producing the desirable:

```py
df_desirable = pl.DataFrame({"index1": [3, 2, 2], "index2": [1, 0, 3], "weight":[1,2,3]})
# shape: (3, 3)
# ┌────────┬────────┬────────┐
# │ index1 ┆ index2 ┆ weight │
# │ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---    │
# │ i64    ┆ i64    ┆ i64    │
# ╞════════╪════════╪════════╡
# │ 3      ┆ 1      ┆ 1      │
# │ 2      ┆ 0      ┆ 2      │
# │ 2      ┆ 3      ┆ 3      │
# └────────┴────────┴────────┘
```

My current method is the following, which isn't terrible, but is there a better way?

```py
df_network.join(
    df_node_index.rename({"index": "index1"}),
    how="left",
    left_on="node1",
    right_on="node",
).join(
    df_node_index.rename({"index": "index2"}),
    how="left",
    left_on="node2",
    right_on="node",
).select(
    ["index1", "index2", "weight"]
).frame_equal(df_desirable) # True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the recently added [`.map_dict`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html#polars.Expr.map_dict)

```
>>> node_index
{'d': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2, 'a': 3}
```

```
df_network.with_columns(
   pl.col("node1", "node2").map_dict(node_index)
)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬────────┐
│ node1 | node2 | weight │
│ ---   | ---   | ---    │
│ i64   | i64   | i64    │
╞═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 3     | 1     | 1      │
│ 2     | 0     | 2      │
│ 2     | 3     | 3      │
└───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Comment: Beautiful! That's fantastic timing :D